# How to make a javascript alert NOT say the name of the page?

Tags: javascript, alert, web-applications, alerts

My webapp alert looks like this:

---

InputCoordinates.html

Latitude must be filled out.

---

I would say this looks unprofessional and rough around the edges. Is there a way to stop the alert from displaying the pagename?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, not with the default javascript alert. You'll need to create a custom alert box of your own.

Comment: show some code ! Have you considered modal popups instead of alert's ?

Comment: Haha the code is just "alert("So and so");", so I didn't bother. I am unfamiliar with modal popups, I'll have to look into that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **can't** manipulate that.
Maybe you take a look at these bastards called modal popups, if youre able to use jQuery.

- http://jquery.iceburg.net/jqModal/

There are non-jquery options, too, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Use an HTML modal box instead of the JavaScript `alert()` Box.

There are plenty of options to choose from on the web, e.g. [here](https://github.com/okonet/modalbox).

Answer (score 2):

I'd advise you not to use "alert".  Use something that allows you to style it yourself, e.g., [jQuery Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).  You can make that modal if necessary (follow the links on the right of the page I sent for add'l examples).