# PHP Alert Box - The Page at localhost says

Tags: javascript

I use alert box in PHP forms and get something like this;

PHP Alert Box - For eg: `The Page at localhost says .. "Your username is invalid"`

Is it possible to customize the text "The Page at localhost says"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a javascript alert NOT say the name of the page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824885/how-to-make-a-javascript-alert-not-say-the-name-of-the-page)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the property of the Browser you're using & You can't modify. Instead You can use a custom javascript alert box.

[jQuery Alert Dialog](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/)

Comment: That's it. Cool. I got an answer!

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot. **`javascript`** alert box title cannot be modified.

Answer (score 0):

The `javascript` `alert()` is an inbuilt method. And you can not override it.
Try jQuery UI Dialog

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

Alert Box Says Can Not Change Because it depends on the browser. In Google Chorme The Alert box properties and firefox the alert box is different. To get rid of this problem you have to use custom alert box.
This link may help you.
https://www.freshdesignweb.com/jquery-javascript-popup-window.html

Answer (score 0):

Alert Box Says Can Not Change Because it depends on the browser. In Google Chorme The Alert box properties and firefox the alert box is different. To get rid of this problem you have to use custom alert box. This link may help you. https://www.freshdesignweb.com/jquery-javascript-popup-window.html

Comment: Welcome n123, could you please add relevant portions of the link directly into your answer?